# accessing static member from non-static function in typescript

Tags: typescript, static-methods, static-members, non-static

I am trying to access a static member from a non-static function in the class, and I get an error saying

> Static member cannot be accessed off an instance variable

this is how my code looks -

```
class myClass {
  public static testStatic: number = 0;
  public increment(): void {
    this.testStatic++;
  }
}
```

From what I understand of static members/methods, we shouldn't access non-static members in static functions, but vice-versa should be possible.
the static member is already created and is valid, so why can't I access from my non-static method?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Access static members from inside the class the same way you would from outside the class:

```
class myClass {
  public static testStatic: number = 0;
  public increment(): void {
    myClass.testStatic++;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but it's not a very good practice. Typescript should have a keyword for that. Something like static:: in php. The reason is you're duplicating the name of your class like this. Basically every instance should know its class, right?

Comment: I don't see why it's needed for classes any more than it's needed for anything else. There isn't a keyword for the name of the enclosing function, the name of the enclosing module, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer something in the spirit of:

```
class myClass{
    public static testStatic: number = 0;
    private class;

    constructor(){
        this.class = myClass;
    }

    public increment(): void {
        this.class.testStatic++;
    }
}
```

One cool thing is that typescript is actually allowing me to use 'class' as a variable.

Comment: It is still duplication, but duplication in one place only - the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

For allowing inheritance you must use inside a instance method in order to don't repeat className:

`<typeof ParentClass>this.constructor`

See the Update section in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244254/1936549