# How to access static members from instance methods in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I try to use a static member from an instance method. I know about [accessing static member from non-static function in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516320/accessing-static-member-from-non-static-function-in-typescript), but I do not want to hard code the class to allow inheritance:

```
class Logger {
  protected static PREFIX = '[info]';

  public log(msg: string) {
    console.log(Logger.PREFIX + ' ' + msg); // What to use instead of Logger` to get the expected result?
  }
}

class Warner extends Logger {
  protected static PREFIX = '[warn]';
}

(new Logger).log('=> should be prefixed [info]');
(new Warner).log('=> should be prefixed [warn]');
```

I've tried things like

```
typeof this.PREFIX
```

Comment: TLDR - `ClassName.property`. For overridden properties, `(<typeof ClassName> this.constructor).property`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You simply need `ClassName.property` :

```
class Logger {
  protected static PREFIX = '[info]';
  public log(message: string): void {
    alert(Logger.PREFIX + string); 
  }
}

class Warner extends Logger {
  protected static PREFIX = '[warn]';
}
```

---

**MORE**

from : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/future-javascript/classes

TypeScript classes support static properties that are shared by all instances of the class. A natural place to put (and access) them is on the class itself and that is what TypeScript does:

```
class Something {
    static instances = 0;
    constructor() {
        Something.instances++;
    }
}

var s1 = new Something();
var s2 = new Something();
console.log(Someting.instances); // 2
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want it to inherit from the particular instance's constructor use `this.constructor`. Sadly you need to use *some* type assertion. I am using `typeof Logger` shown below:

```
class Logger {
  protected static PREFIX = '[info]';
  public log(message: string): void {
    var logger = <typeof Logger>this.constructor; 
    alert(logger.PREFIX + message); 
  }
}

class Warner extends Logger {
  protected static PREFIX = '[warn]';
}
```

Comment: I know about using the ClassName.property. But then it will use Logger.PREFIX even in subclasses that have their own .PREFIX defined.

Comment: Updated the question to be more clear about the expected result.

Comment: @SimonHürlimann Updated the answer to take that into account ;)

Comment: It seems I can use `<typeof Logger>` instead of `<any>` in the typecast. This seems more appropriate.

Comment: @SimonHürlimann I knew I was being lazy and hence left ambiguity with *some*. Thanks for clearing that up. Example updated for future peeps :)

Comment: Any way to make this work if Logger.log is static? I would really need that behavior, but can't seem to find out how to do it.

Comment: This does not work. 

For example: 

```
const a = new Logger();
a.log('a ')
const b = new Warner();
b.log('b ')
```
Both log Info

Comment: Why this answer is voted up? Warner instance printed out [info]

Comment: @JimmyKane: Your example works correctly for me (after changing `alert()` to `console.log()`) with node v16.17.0, TS v4.4.2.