# Late Static Binding and Instance Methods in TypeScript

Tags: python, typescript, static, polymorphism, instance

Am very curious how/why the following trickery is needed in TypeScript. Was playing around with basic `class` and `static` constructs, then inheritance, and finally referencing `static` properties from `instance` methods. I might not ever implement anything this way... but I did get quite confused *why* the following works:

```
class Foo {
  msg: string;
  static name: string = 'Foo';
  static sayHi(): string {
    return `hello from ${this.name}`;
  }
  constructor() {
    // this.msg = `I am ${Foo.name}`;
    //   2x `I am Foo`

    // this.msg = `I am ${this.name}`;
    //   error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Foo'.

    // this.msg = `I am ${this.constructor.name}`;
    //   error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'.

    const cls = <typeof Foo>this.constructor;
    this.msg = `I am ${cls.name}`;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  static name: string = 'Bar';
}

console.log(Foo.sayHi());   // hello from Foo
console.log(Bar.sayHi());   // hello from Bar

console.log((new Foo()).msg);   // I am Foo
console.log((new Bar()).msg);   // I am Bar
```

(i'm on `tsc 1.8.10`, the **UPDATE** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29244254/1345249) got it working)

If you jump to @basarat's response, WHY does the type assertion magically make everything work?

Compared to similar python:

```
class Foo(object):
  name = 'Foo'
  @classmethod
  def sayHi(cls):
    return 'hello from {}'.format(cls.name)
  def __init__(self):
    self.msg = 'I am {}'.format(self.name);

class Bar(Foo):
  name = 'Bar'

print(Foo.sayHi())  # hello from Foo
print(Bar.sayHi())  # hello from Bar

print(Foo().msg)  # I am Foo
print(Bar().msg)  # I am Bar
```

Comment: What do you mean *"got it working"*? What happened before you added the explicit typing?

Comment: tried to indicate with comments in the constructor(). _guess i failed_

Comment: Ah sorry, so you did. They are really only warnings from the TS compiler, the code should still run just fine.