# Access static property in default nameless class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

If I define a class like this (in a file called. MyClass.ts)

```
export default class {
    static someProperty = 1;

    someMethod() {
       var a = ????.someProperty
    }

}
```

How do I access someProperty. 
Using `this.someProperty` does not work, obviously. Neither can a name be used. Had it been a named class it could be accessed through `SomeClassName.someProperty`.

If I load the module in another file. I can access it via:

```
MyClass.someProperty
```

Comment: If it's a static property that's how you'd access it internally as well... is it not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access static members from instance methods in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29244119/how-to-access-static-members-from-instance-methods-in-typescript)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Do you mean `this.someMethod`? Or just `someMethod`? Neither will work.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes you would use its name. Problem here is that the class does not have a name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using an anonymous class expression here. I could be wrong, but I believe naming the class expression is the only way you could access that variable.

```
 export default class ClassName {
    static someProperty = 1;

    someMethod() {
        return ClassName.someProperty;
    }

}
```

Your consumers can still name that class whatever they want (MyClass in your earlier example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
this.constructor.someProperty
```

Comment: Using this gives a compiler error: "Property 'someProperty' does not exist on type 'Function'"

Comment: To use it this way unfortunately you need to cast type, like so: `const x = (<typeof YourClassName>this.constructor).someStaticProp`